# Unity C#; Why Is My Game Loading The Default State After I Save It In A Different State?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making my first game in unity. It is a clicker game, and am working on saving and loading. There is a saving button and a loading button, all linked up to the scripts as they are supposed to, but for some reason, after I press the save button and load button, it loads the default state of the game. Can anyone help me with this? Here are the codes for both scripts, aswell as the script for GlobalTamanduas:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Load : MonoBehaviour {

    public int SaveTamanduas;
    public int SaveCash;
    public int SaveBargainCost;
    public int SaveBargainLevel;
    public int SaveCloneCost;
    public int SaveCloneLevel;
    public GameObject LoadButton;

    public void Start() {
        SaveTamanduas = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveTamanduas");
        GlobalTamanduas.TamanduaCount = SaveTamanduas;
        SaveCash = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveCash");
        GlobalCash.CashCount = SaveCash;
        SaveBargainCost = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveBargainCost");
        BargainButton.Cost = SaveBargainCost;
        SaveCloneCost = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveCloneCost");
        CloneButton.Cost = SaveCloneCost;
        SaveCloneLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveCloneLevel");
        CloneButton.Level = SaveCloneLevel;
        SaveBargainLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveBargainLevel");
        BargainButton.Level = SaveBargainLevel;


    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Save : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int TamanduaCount = Convert.ToInt32(GlobalTamanduas.TamanduaCount);
    public static int CashCount = Convert.ToInt32(GlobalCash.CashCount);
    public static int BargainCostCount = Convert.ToInt32(BargainButton.Cost);
    public static int BargainLevelCount = Convert.ToInt32(BargainButton.Level);
    public static int CloneCostCount = Convert.ToInt32(CloneButton.Cost);
    public static int CloneLevelCount = Convert.ToInt32(CloneButton.Level);
    public GameObject SaveButton;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        
    }

    public void SaveTheGame()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveTamanduas", TamanduaCount);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCash", CashCount);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveBargainCost", BargainCostCount);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveBargainLevel", BargainLevelCount);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCloneCost", CloneCostCount);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCloneLevel", CloneLevelCount);
    }

}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GlobalTamanduas : MonoBehaviour {

    public static double TamanduaCount = 0;
    public GameObject TamanduaDisplay;
    public double InternalTamandua;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        InternalTamandua = TamanduaCount;
        TamanduaDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Tamanduas: " + InternalTamandua;
        if (TamanduaCount == 0)
        {
            if (GlobalCash.CashCount == 0)
            {
                TamanduaCount += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem 1

By default `PlayerPrefs` are only saved in `OnApplicationQuit`!

In order to "manually" force a saving of the `PlayerPrefs` you need to call [`PlayerPrefs.Save`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html) after editing the values.

> By default Unity writes preferences to disk during `OnApplicationQuit()`. In cases when the game crashes or otherwise prematuraly exits, you might want to write the PlayerPrefs at sensible 'checkpoints' in your game.

```
public void SaveTheGame()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveTamanduas", TamanduaCount);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCash", CashCount);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveBargainCost", BargainCostCount);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveBargainLevel", BargainLevelCount);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCloneCost", CloneCostCount);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCloneLevel", CloneLevelCount);

    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

#### Problem 2

`int`, `float`, `double` etc are **`structs`** and thereby **value types**!

You are however only assigning them **once** in

```
public static int TamanduaCount = Convert.ToInt32(GlobalTamanduas.TamanduaCount);
public static int CashCount = Convert.ToInt32(GlobalCash.CashCount);
public static int BargainCostCount = Convert.ToInt32(BargainButton.Cost);
public static int BargainLevelCount = Convert.ToInt32(BargainButton.Level);
public static int CloneCostCount = Convert.ToInt32(CloneButton.Cost);
public static int CloneLevelCount = Convert.ToInt32(CloneButton.Level);
```

This does **NOT** mean they are automatically updated whenever e.g. `GlobalTamanduas.TamanduaCount` changes! Since you never assign them again they will keep forever their default values (or the once that were set in these static fields in the moment the static constructor was executed).

So what you rather want to do would be get rid of these `static` fields in the `Save` class and rather use

```
public void SaveTheGame()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveTamanduas", Convert.ToInt32(GlobalTamanduas.TamanduaCount));
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCash", Convert.ToInt32(GlobalCash.CashCount));
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveBargainCost", Convert.ToInt32(BargainButton.Cost));
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveBargainLevel",  Convert.ToInt32(BargainButton.Level));
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCloneCost", Convert.ToInt32(CloneButton.Cost));
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCloneLevel", Convert.ToInt32(CloneButton.Level));

    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

In a similar manner there is no need / complete redundancy to keep the values all in local fields when loading. Simply apply them to their according classes and do not additionally store them in the `Load` class.

---

#### Further Notes

You know btw that there is also `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat` and `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat` so why not simply using `float` instead of `double` and use them without the need of any conversation/parsing?

Especially when you increase them in full steps like in

```
TamanduaCount += 1;
```

why is it not simply an `int`?

And finally I would not all the time poll a value in `Update` but rather make the whole thing event driven by using a property like e.g.

```
public class GlobalTamanduas : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private static double _tamanduaCount;
    public static double TamanduaCount
    {
        get => _tamanduaCount;
        set
        {
            _tamanduaCount = value;
            // Inform anyone who is interested in (listening to) this event
            OnTamanduaChanged?.Invoke(_tamanduaCount);
        
        }
    }
    public GameObject TamanduaDisplay;
    public static Action<double> OnTamanduaChanged;

    void Awake()
    {
        // Start listening to the event
        OnTamanduaChanged += HandleTamandueChanged;

        // Handle it once right now
        HandleTamanduaChanged(TamanduaCount);
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        // Important: always clean up listeners to avoid errors
        OnTamanduaChanged -= HandleTamandueChanged;
    }
    
    void HandleTamandueChanged(double count)
    {
        TamanduaDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Tamanduas: " + count;
        if (count == 0 && GlobalCash.CashCount == 0)
        {    
            TamanduaCount = 1;
        }
    }
}
```